# systemd-analyze blame provides a list repeated many times in terminal

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am facing with very slow boot time on Ubuntu 18.04.1.
After running the command

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

in terminal, I've got a very long list containing repeated sublists

```
me@wht:/boot$ systemd-analyze blame
      2.436s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      2.005s postfix@-.service
      1.788s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.136s snapd.service
      1.127s mysql.service
       793ms dev-sda2.device
       775ms fwupd.service
       707ms NetworkManager.service
       569ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       512ms udisks2.service
       503ms plymouth-start.service
       503ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       388ms accounts-daemon.service
       378ms grub-common.service
       377ms ModemManager.service
       357ms thermald.service
       317ms polkit.service
       308ms virtualbox-guest-utils.service
       295ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
       284ms avahi-daemon.service
       277ms dev-loop9.device
       249ms dev-loop10.device
       248ms snap-core18-941.mount
       247ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-86.mount
       238ms dev-loop8.device
       234ms snap-core-6964.mount
       234ms dev-loop0.device
       234ms dev-loop1.device
       227ms dev-loop12.device
       222ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
       221ms dev-loop2.device
       215ms dev-loop11.device
       215ms snap-core-6818.mount
       214ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-352.mount
       212ms dev-loop3.device
       200ms snap-core-6673.mount
       199ms dev-loop14.device
       197ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
       192ms dev-loop7.device
       187ms dev-loop5.device
       186ms dev-loop13.device
       180ms dev-loop16.device
       178ms dev-loop19.device
       178ms dev-loop6.device
       176ms dev-loop4.device
       175ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
lines 1-46...skipping...
      2.436s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      2.005s postfix@-.service
      1.788s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.136s snapd.service
      1.127s mysql.service
       793ms dev-sda2.device
       775ms fwupd.service
       707ms NetworkManager.service
       569ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       512ms udisks2.service
       503ms plymouth-start.service
```

I've checked the following directory /boot

```
abi-4.15.0-36-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-4.4.0-137-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-4.15.0-36-generic      retpoline-4.15.0-36-generic
config-4.4.0-137-generic      retpoline-4.4.0-137-generic
grub                          System.map-4.15.0-36-generic
initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic  System.map-4.4.0-137-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-137-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
lost+found                    vmlinuz-4.4.0-137-generic
memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz-4.4.0-137-generic.efi.signed
```

There are new files belonging to Bionic Beaver and old files. Are these old files the reason for the slow boot time? Should I delete the old files?

```
Startup finished in 33.342s (kernel) + 6.901s (userspace) = 40.243s
graphical.target reached after 6.897s in userspace
```

According to

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

I've got the following:

```
graphical.target @6.897s
└─multi-user.target @6.897s
  └─mysql.service @4.891s +1.127s
    └─network-online.target @4.889s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @3.101s +1.788s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.390s +707ms
          └─dbus.service @2.377s
            └─basic.target @2.372s
              └─sockets.target @2.372s
                └─snapd.socket @2.371s +951us
                  └─sysinit.target @2.363s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @2.226s +137ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @2.216s +6ms
                        └─local-fs.target @2.213s
                          └─run-user-118.mount @4.953s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @1.396s
                              └─keyboard-setup.service @1.329s +67ms
                                └─systemd-journald.socket @1.329s
                                  └─system.slice @1.328s
                                    └─-.slice @1.327s
```

The output from `sudo systemctl status snapd` is [here](https://pastebin.com/7AeZLjTn).

The output from `pgrep snap` is 1020.

Comment: Don't delete anything. Post the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: @user535733 an edit to my question.

Comment: The /boot is normal, you can boot old kernels from the grub boot screen. It's good to keep the last kernel you used so that if an update fails you can still boot. You have a load of loopback devices mounted, I think that's just how snap apps work, it all looks pretty normal to me except the duplicate of eg snapd.service, have you got 2 versions installed? What does `sudo sysyemctl status snapd` show, how about `pgrep snap` and `mount`? Use pastebin.com to post long outputs.

Comment: @pbhj `sudo sysyemctl status snapd` shows that snapd.service is active (PID 1020). More details on https://pastebin.com/7AeZLjTn . The output is long and includes the same repeating content about snapd.service status. Should I do anything about it at all? Should I disable autostart for this service?

Comment: How long is a "slow boot time" to you? Your output shows reaching the login screen in under seven seconds.

Comment: @user535733 it takes about 1 minute 40 seconds before the login screen appears. I  cannot identify the problem.

Comment: Time how long each step takes: BIOS, bootloader, kernel loading, OS loading, etc. Tip: Record the boot with your phone to get accurate times. You tell us which steps take how long. Help us to help you.