# Is it possible to start snapd.service after boot finishes?

Tags: boot, snap, services

`snapd.service` takes a relatively long time to run at boot, so to speed up booting can I instead start the service after booting is finished?

here is the result of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
> systemd-analyze blame                                           Sal 14 Ara 2021 14:58:50
29.098s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                       >
17.111s dev-sda3.device                                                                  >
16.480s snapd.service                                                                    >
13.185s networkd-dispatcher.service                                                      >
11.886s udisks2.service                                                                  >
 8.401s accounts-daemon.service                                                          >
 7.103s dev-loop3.device                                                                 >
 6.743s dev-loop22.device                                                                >
 6.652s dev-loop15.device                                                                >
 6.520s systemd-journal-flush.service                                                    >
 6.420s dev-loop2.device                                                                 >
 6.385s dev-loop6.device                                                                 >
 6.367s avahi-daemon.service                                                             >
 6.360s bluetooth.service                                                                >
 6.356s NetworkManager.service                                                           >
 6.307s polkit.service                                                                   >
 6.256s dev-loop1.device                                                                 >
 6.121s dev-loop13.device                                                                >
 6.060s dev-loop21.device                                                                >
 5.793s switcheroo-control.service                                                       >
 5.786s thermald.service                                                                 >
 5.783s systemd-logind.service                                                           >
 5.779s wpa_supplicant.service                                                           >
 5.608s gpu-manager.service                                                              >
 5.573s dev-loop17.device                                                                >
 5.570s dev-loop9.device                                                                 >
 5.476s ModemManager.service                                                             >
 5.262s dev-loop20.device                                                                >
 5.243s dev-loop18.device                                                                >
 5.104s dev-loop16.device                                                                >
 5.049s dev-loop12.device                                                                >
 5.035s dev-loop14.device                                                                >
 4.958s dev-loop19.device                                                                >
 4.730s dev-loop10.device                                                                >
 4.539s plymouth-read-write.service                                                      >
 4.410s dev-loop11.device                                                                >
 4.209s dev-loop8.device                                                                 >
 3.959s zebra.service                                                                    >
 3.860s systemd-sysctl.service                                                           >
 3.811s dev-loop4.device                                                                 >
 3.642s dev-loop7.device                                                                 >
 3.591s apport.service                                                                   >
 3.566s dev-loop5.device                                                                 >
 3.121s rsyslog.service                                                                  >
 3.119s e2scrub_reap.service                                                             >
 3.075s snap-bare-5.mount                                                                >
 2.958s dev-loop0.device                                                                 >
 2.799s snap-code-82.mount                                                               >
 2.692s snap-code-83.mount                                                               >
 2.678s snap-core-11798.mount                                                            >
 2.610s snap-core-11993.mount                                                            >
 2.499s gdm.service                                                                      >
 2.319s snap-core18-2246.mount                                                           >
 2.179s tlp.service                                                                      >
 2.055s snap-core18-2253.mount                                                           >
 2.039s fwupd.service                                                                    >
 2.009s virtualbox.service                                                               >
 1.893s systemd-udevd.service                                                            >
 1.774s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                   >
 1.750s apparmor.service                                                                 >
 1.745s systemd-resolved.service                                                         >
 1.692s secureboot-db.service                                                            >
 1.633s colord.service                                                                   >
 1.434s snap-core20-1242.mount                                                           >
 1.367s snap-core20-1270.mount                                                           >
 1.344s ssh.service                                                                      >
 1.305s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-72.mount                                           >
 1.270s packagekit.service                                                               >
 1.270s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-77.mount                                           >
 1.262s snapd.apparmor.service                                                           >
 1.242s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-92804264\x2dc37f\x2d48cb\x2d8ec5\x2d49bc5be832fa>
 1.234s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                               >
 1.183s systemd-random-seed.service                                                      >
 1.143s nvidia-persistenced.service                                                      >
 1.138s systemd-modules-load.service                                                     >
 1.015s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-76.mount                                           >
  967ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-90BC\x2dAD77.service                            >
  966ms upower.service                                                                   >
  957ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-87.mount                                           >
  943ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                                          >
  897ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1519.mount                                          >
  802ms user@1000.service
```

and the results of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
> systemd-analyze critical-chain                          33.4s  Sal 14 Ara 2021 14:59:39
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 6.867s
└─multi-user.target @1min 6.867s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @48.059s +747ms
    └─snapd.service @31.576s +16.480s
      └─basic.target @30.982s
        └─sockets.target @30.981s
          └─snapd.socket @30.980s +1ms
            └─sysinit.target @30.880s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @28.087s +1.262s
                └─apparmor.service @26.334s +1.750s
                  └─local-fs.target @26.332s
                    └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @53.006s
                      └─run-user-1000.mount @44.989s
                        └─swap.target @24.765s
                          └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-de61f134\x2d705a\x2d4c98\x2d89f7\x2d04a0b>
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-de61f134\x2d705a\x2d4c98\x2d89f7\x2d04a>
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with the following specs:

```
> lshw                                                            Sal 14 Ara 2021 18:21:47
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
hasan-nitro-an515-43        
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 14GiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD Ryzen 7 3750H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1352MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate sme ssbd sev ibpb vmmcall sev_es fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca cpufreq
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: IOMMU
             product: Raven/Raven2 IOMMU
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 0.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:00.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:c1000000-c1ffffff ioport:90000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:75 memory:c1000000-c1ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27 memory:c2800000-c28fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: BC501 NVMe Solid State Drive 512GB
                vendor: SK hynix
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:44 memory:c2800000-c2803fff
              *-nvme0
                   description: NVMe device
                   product: HFM256GDJTNG-8310A
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: /dev/nvme0
                   version: 80002C00
                   serial: CY9CN00101150CE4Y
                   configuration: nqn=nqn.2014.08.org.nvmexpress:1c5c1c5cCY9CN00101150CE4Y   HFM256GDJTNG-8310A state=live
                 *-namespace
                      description: NVMe namespace
                      physical id: 1
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.6
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:28 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:c2700000-c27fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: enp3s0
                version: 25
                serial: 08:97:98:8f:fa:bf
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: cap_list ethernet physical
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
                resources: irq:34 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c2704000-c2704fff memory:c2700000-c2703fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.7
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:29 memory:c2000000-c21fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlp4s0
                version: 32
                serial: e4:aa:ea:50:6c:87
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.46 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:79 memory:c2000000-c21fffff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus A
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:30 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:c2300000-c26fffff ioport:b0000000(size=270532608)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Picasso
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                version: c1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
                resources: irq:43 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:c2600000-c267ffff
           *-multimedia:0
                description: Audio device
                product: Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:82 memory:c2688000-c268bfff
           *-generic
                description: Encryption controller
                product: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.2
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=ccp latency=0
                resources: irq:71 memory:c2500000-c25fffff memory:c268c000-c268dfff
           *-usb:0
                description: USB controller
                product: Raven USB 3.1
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.3
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: xhci cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:33 memory:c2400000-c24fffff
           *-usb:1
                description: USB controller
                product: Raven USB 3.1
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.4
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.4
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:43 memory:c2300000-c23fffff
           *-multimedia:1
                description: Audio device
                product: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.6
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.6
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:45 memory:c2680000-c2687fff
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:31 memory:c2200000-c22fffff
           *-sata
                description: SATA controller
                product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                version: 61
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: sata ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
                resources: irq:72 memory:c2200000-c22007ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: FCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 61
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: FCH LPC Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 51
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 108
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:9
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 109
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.6
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:10
          description: Host bridge
          product: Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10a
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.7
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device FUJ7401
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user
```

Comment: Please provide a list of timings of each service during boot (fi: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153127/systemd-analyze-blame-provides-a-list-repeated-many-times-in-terminal ). Booting is done in parallel so you are unlikely to improve boot time. Another approach: why not ditch snap totally? Replace all snap installs by their original counterpart.

Comment: From this I would assume snapd is not the issue. The timing here reads like your system is an i3 or i5. Can you add the processor and the brand of the boot disk?

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for the answer, I added my system specs.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed could delay the startup of snapd. After startup, you then would be unable to start snap applications until the daemon has loaded. However, you will at most shave off less than half of a second of your startup time.

Comment: can you give me more information on how I would delay the service startup?

Comment: Delay is not universal. Some conditional-based solution would be better. Like [After=network-online.target](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/).

Answer (score 0):

The timing in "blame"does not suggest any long waits. This seems normal for a system like an i3 with a normal hdd.

Just a few of those services ...

For `networkd-dispatcher.service` see [Extremely slow Kubuntu Boot (18.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181672/extremely-slow-kubuntu-boot-18-04-lts)

For `dev-sda3.device` make sure the timing does not include a filesystem check with `systemctl status dev-sda3.device`.

`plymouth-quit-wait.service`: loads the boot-up logo at the beginning of the boot-up process and **then waits until the boot-up process has finished so it unloads the splash screen**.  So those 29s are mostly it waiting on the other services.

`bluetooth.service` when you do not use BT... disable it.